# ggplot2 annotation with superscripts

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I include a superscript in ggplot annotation? I want to display Rsuperscript2 = somevalue 
I tried using parse=TRUE inside annotate.. It gave me = Rsuperscript2 , somevalue instead

```
lm1 <- lm(dData$RF ~ dData$Exp -1)
lb1 <- paste("R^2 = ", round(summary(lm1)$r.squared,4))
p1 <- ggplot(dData, aes(x=dData$Exp, y=dData$RF)) +
  scale_x_continuous("Experimental") + 
  scale_y_continuous("Predicted") + 
  geom_point() + geom_smooth(method="lm") + 
  annotate("text", x=max(dData$Exp), y=min(dData$RF)+1, label=lb1, 
           hjust=1, size=3, vjust=1)
```

Comment: Not a reproducible example

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Is the problem with superscripts or with the equals sign?  Switching to == in the expression, with `parse=TRUE` works for me.  Not having your `dData`, here is a dummy example.

```
lb1 <- paste("R^2 == ", round(runif(1),4))
qplot(1:10, 1:10) + 
  annotate("text", x=2, y=8, label=lb1, parse=TRUE)
```

[image]